# Graceful termination of a Java Application

Tags: java, shell, unix, jar, java.util.logging

I have a shell script which is used to launch the java application.Shell script has following commands in it to launch the class which contain main method :

```
_MainJava="com.abc.launchers.AgentLauncher"
_ConfigFilePath="/home/lego/ConfigProperties"
_LogFilePath="/home/lego/Logs/"

java -jar "${_MainJava}" "${_ConfigFilePath}" "${_LogFilePath}"
```

I launch this script through command prompt.

Java code has a JMS listener which is always in listening mode .So this java code is always up and never terminates.

Now I want to terminate this java program.One way is (and which I do every time) is terminate by pressing "Cntrl+c" which is killing the program by force and this way I cannot print logs like, "Terminating agent".

If I know in advance that agent will be terminated(like some condition),I can print the logs and do System.exit(0).
But I cannot know this in advance as agent will only be terminated during maintenance time.

Please help me to understand how can I achieve this.

As suuggested in comment section ,shutdown hook is the perfect option.
Now I have been trying to implement it in my test code.My code is like following :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() 
        { 
          public void run() 
          { 
            System.out.println("Shutdown Hook is running !"); 
          } 
        }); 
        System.out.println("Application Terminating ...");

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Running");
        }

    }
```

In eclipse IDE, I go in debug tab where I see this code running continuously ,I do right click -> terminate and it doesn't print anything.

Final output :

Running
Running
Running
.
.
.
.

Comment: Yes this is the perfect way to do it.....I have edited my question with another problem I am facing...see if you can tackle the issue.

Comment: I don't use eclipse but it's likely that "terminate" sends SIGKILL instead of SIGTERM, and then shutdown hook will be ignored. Try running your class from the command line and hit Ctrl+C